# LINQ query2 from query

Tags: c#, sql, linq

i'm learning the book:

**LINQ to Objects Using C# 4.0**

Ok, my question:

I have two class: **Contact** and **CallLog**. It look like:

```
public class Contact
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
};

public class CallLog
    {
        public string Number { get; set; }
        public int Duration { get; set; }
        public bool Incoming { get; set; }
        public DateTime When { get; set; }
    }
```

Relation: **Contact.Phone equals CallLog.Number**

Two Class have method: SampleData(). This metod return a simple List<> with Contacts and CallLogs.

```
List<Contact> contacts = Contact.SampleData();
List<CallLog> callLogs = CallLog.SampleData();
```

I have now query, which return a result sort by numbers of calls foreach Contact (exactly contact, who calls more that 0).

```
var query = (from callLog in callLogs
                        group callLog by callLog.Number into g
                        select new
                        {
                            contact = contacts.Where(c=>c.Phone == g.Key),
                            how_much = g.Count(),
                        });

foreach(var q in query){
     foreach(var qq in q.contact){
          Console.WriteLine(qq.FirstName + " calls " + q.how_much + " times");
     }
}
```

It return for example:

*Stephan calls 5 times*

*Sophie calls 2 times*

*Tom calls 5 times*

etc...

now I want to group by time of calls (5 times, 2 times ...), well i'm writin next query by query:

```
var query2 = from q in query
                         group q by q.how_much into g
                         select new
                         {
                             what_number       = g.Key, // f.e 5 times
                             count_what_number = g.Count(), // 5 times have 2 person
                             who               = g // collection for person
                         };
foreach (var q in query2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(q.what_number + " calls have done: ( " + q.count_what_number + ") peoples"));
                foreach (var qq in q.who)
                {
                    foreach (var qqq in qq.contact)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("   " + qqq.FirstName);
                    }
                }
            }
```

result:

```
5 calls have done: (2 peoples):
     Stephan
     Tom
2 calls have done: (1 peoples):       
     Sophie
```

**It's any way to make this query by 1 query (group by group not in two queries)?**

Comment: If you have found an answer to your question, please post and/or accept an answer rather than editing your question.

Comment: where's accept button? i'm new.

Comment: Use the "Your Answer" box to answer your own question. Then if you desire, you can use the "check" to indicate it as the accepted answer. Do not edit the question text to include the answer, and do not use edit the title. We already have mechanisms in place for answering and indicating that an answer has been accepted.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram is correct. I would recommend that you additionally go through the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and earn the [Informed badge](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2600/informed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another way to do that:

```
List<Contact> contacts = Contact.SampleData();
List<CallLog> callLogs = CallLog.SampleData();

var q = from callLog in callLogs
        group callLog by callLog.Number into g
        join c in contacts on g.Key equals c.Phone
        let row = new { g = g, c = c }
        group row by row.g.Count() into g2
        select new
        {
            People = g2.Select((x) => x.c.FirstName).ToArray(),
            Count = g2.Key
        };

foreach (var qq in q)
{
    Console.WriteLine(qq.Count + ": " + string.Join(", ", qq.People));
}
```

Prints something like:

```
4: Tom, John
2: Adam
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
 var query = (from callLog in callLogs
                         group callLog by callLog.Number into g
                         select new
                         {
                             who = contacts.Where(c => c.Phone == g.Key),
                             how_much = g.Count()
                         }).GroupBy(c=>c.how_much);

     foreach (var q in query)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(q.Key + " " + q.Count());
                    foreach (var qq in q)
                    {
                        foreach (var qqq in qq.who)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(qqq.FirstName + " " + qqq.LastName);
                        }
                    }
                }
```