# Linq left join and where

Tags: c#, sql, linq

```
i'm learning the book:
```

**LINQ to Objects Using C# 4.0**

Ok, my question:

I have two class: **Contact** and **CallLog**. It look like:

```
public class Contact
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
};

public class CallLog
    {
        public string Number { get; set; }
        public int Duration { get; set; }
        public bool Incoming { get; set; }
        public DateTime When { get; set; }
    }
```

Relation: **Contact.Phone equals CallLog.Number**

Two Class have method: SampleData(). This metod return a simple List<> with Contacts and CallLogs.

```
List<Contact> contacts = Contact.SampleData();
List<CallLog> callLogs = CallLog.SampleData();
```

My query is: how many calls do each contact.

```
var query2 = (from contact in contacts
                         join callLog in callLogs on contact.Phone equals callLog.Number into joined
                         from callLog in joined.Where(p=>p.Incoming == false).DefaultIfEmpty()

                         select new
                         {
                             who = contact.FirstName + " " + contact.LastName + " " + contact.Phone,
                             how_many = callLog != null ? callLogs.Where(s =>s.Number == contact.Phone).Count() : 0
                         }).Select(p=>p).Distinct();
            foreach (var q in query2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(q.who + " " + q.how_many);
            }
```

the result:

Tom XXXX 555-555-555 calls 2 times

Sophie YYYY 333-333-333 calls 3 times

Mark ZZZZ 111-111-111 calls 0 times

Now i want to choose only callLog where Incoming == true:

```
var query2 = (from contact in contacts
                         join callLog in callLogs.Where(p=>p.Incomming == true) on contact.Phone equals callLog.Number into joined
                         from callLog in joined.Where(p=>p.Incoming == false).DefaultIfEmpty()

                         select new
                         {
                             who = contact.FirstName + " " + contact.LastName + " " + contact.Phone,
                             how_many = callLog != null ? callLogs.Where(s =>s.Number == contact.Phone).Count() : 0
                         }).Select(p=>p).Distinct();
            foreach (var q in query2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(q.who + " " + q.how_many);
            }
```

(look at the second line in new query2)
but result is same:

Tom XXXX 555-555-555 calls 2 times

Sophie YYYY 333-333-333 calls 3 times

Mark ZZZZ 111-111-111 calls 0 times

how could i fix it?

Comment: Looks pretty similar to your previous question!

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ query2 from query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24600614/linq-query2-from-query)

Comment: no! now i'm using leftjoin..i'm learning, its bad?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
  var query2 = (from contact in contacts
                                 join callLog in callLogs on contact.Phone equals callLog.Number into joined
                                 from callLog in joined.Where(p=>p.Incoming == true).DefaultIfEmpty()

                                 select new
                                 {
                                     who = contact.FirstName + " " + contact.LastName + " " + contact.Phone,
                                     how_many = callLog != null ? callLogs.Where(s =>s.Number == contact.Phone).Count() : 0
                                 }).Select(p=>p).Distinct();
foreach (var q in query2)
{
  Console.WriteLine(q.who + " " + q.how_many);
}
```

Comment: did you change p=>p.Incoming == false to p=>p.Incoming == true

Comment: solved...look: how_many = callLog != null ? callLog(...) here must be joined and in second line change callLogs to callLogs.Where(p=>p.Incoming == true), thanks for help and sorry for mistakes :)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the problem instead of the code, I think the following better expresses what you're trying to do:

```
var contacts = new List<Contact>
{
    new Contact { FirstName = "Tom", LastName = "Jones", Phone = "555-555-555" },
    new Contact { FirstName = "Sophie", LastName = "Monk", Phone = "333-333-333" },
    new Contact { FirstName = "Mark", LastName = "Twain", Phone = "111-111-111" }
};

var callLogs = new List<CallLog>
{
    new CallLog { Number = "555-555-555", Incoming = true },
    new CallLog { Number = "555-555-555", Incoming = true },
    new CallLog { Number = "333-333-333", Incoming = true },
    new CallLog { Number = "333-333-333", Incoming = true },
    new CallLog { Number = "333-333-333", Incoming = true }
};

var data = contacts.Select(c => new 
    {
        who = string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", c.FirstName, c.LastName, c.Phone),
        how_many = callLogs.Count(l => l.Number == c.Phone && l.Incoming)
    }).ToList();

data.Dump();

}

public class Contact
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
}

public class CallLog
{
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public int Duration { get; set; }
    public bool Incoming { get; set; }
    public DateTime When { get; set; }
```

Sample written in Linqpad, copy/paste it straight into the editor and you should see the following output:

- who how_many
- Tom Jones 555-555-555 2
- Sophie Monk 333-333-333 3
- Mark Twain 111-111-111 0

Comment: thanks you! i solved my problem (later i can insert my solution - 10 hours..) but its too good :-)